# Nesting Drag and Drop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m working in mvc and got a Requirement where i need to Drag a list and add into another list in the same view .I have Got a solution by using Sortable Plugin J query

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

But Above link can only drag to the Parent node not To the nested node.I hope i have made myself clear.I want my list to be dragble in nested Li as well
thanks in advance.
[image]